# Sort using LINQ query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

A sequence of information about goods `goodList` of type `Good` and a sequence of prices of
goods in various stores `storePriceList` of type `StorePrice` are given. Each element of the
`goodList` sequence includes the *Product SKU, Category, Country of origin* fields.
Each element of the `storePriceList` sequence includes the *Product SKU, Store Title,
Price* fields.

For each country of origin get the number of stores offering goods manufactured in that
country, as well as the minimum price for goods from this country for all stores (CountryStat
values). If no product is found for a certain country that is presented in any store, then the
number of stores and the minimum price is assumed to be 0. Sort the list by country of origin.

Example:

```
goodList: new[]
{
    new Good{Id = 1, Country = "Ukraine", Category = "Food"},
    new Good{Id = 2, Country = "Ukraine", Category = "Food"},
    new Good{Id = 3, Country = "Ukraine", Category = "Food"},
    new Good{Id = 4, Country = "Ukraine", Category = "Food"},
    new Good{Id = 5, Country = "Germany", Category = "Food"},
    new Good{Id = 6, Country = "Germany", Category = "Food"},
    new Good{Id = 7, Country = "Germany", Category = "Food"},
    new Good{Id = 8, Country = "Germany", Category = "Food"},
    new Good{Id = 9, Country = "Greece", Category = "Food"},
    new Good{Id = 10, Country = "Greece", Category = "Food"},
    new Good{Id = 11, Country = "Greece", Category = "Food"},
    new Good{Id = 12, Country = "Italy", Category = "Food"},
    new Good{Id = 13, Country = "Italy", Category = "Food"},
    new Good{Id = 14, Country = "Italy", Category = "Food"},
    new Good{Id = 15, Country = "Slovenia", Category = "Food"}
}

storePriceList: new[]
{
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 1, Price = 1.25M, Shop = "shop1"},
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 3, Price = 2.25M, Shop = "shop1"},
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 5, Price = 4.25M, Shop = "shop1"},
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 7, Price = 9.25M, Shop = "shop1"},
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 9, Price = 11.25M, Shop = "shop1"},
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 11, Price = 12.25M, Shop = "shop1"},
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 13, Price = 13.25M, Shop = "shop1"},
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 14, Price = 14.25M, Shop = "shop1"},
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 5, Price = 11.25M, Shop = "shop2"},
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 4, Price = 16.25M, Shop = "shop2"},
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 3, Price = 18.25M, Shop = "shop2"},
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 2, Price = 11.25M, Shop = "shop2"},
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 1, Price = 1.50M, Shop = "shop2"},
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 3, Price = 4.25M, Shop = "shop3"},
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 7, Price = 3.25M, Shop = "shop3"},
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 10, Price = 13.25M, Shop = "shop3"},
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 14, Price = 14.25M, Shop = "shop3"},
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 3, Price = 11.25M, Shop = "shop4"},
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 2, Price = 14.25M, Shop = "shop4"},
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 12, Price = 2.25M, Shop = "shop4"},
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 6, Price = 5.25M, Shop = "shop4"},
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 8, Price = 6.25M, Shop = "shop4"},
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 10, Price = 11.25M, Shop = "shop4"},
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 4, Price = 15.25M, Shop = "shop5"},
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 7, Price = 18.25M, Shop = "shop5"},
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 8, Price = 13.25M, Shop = "shop5"},
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 12, Price = 14.25M, Shop = "shop5"},
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 1, Price = 3.25M, Shop = "shop6"},
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 3, Price = 2.25M, Shop = "shop6"},
    new StorePrice{GoodId = 1, Price = 1.20M, Shop = "shop7"}
}
```

Expected Result:

```
expected: new[]
{
    new CountryStat{Country = "Germany", MinPrice = 3.25M, StoresNumber = 5},
    new CountryStat{Country = "Greece", MinPrice = 11.25M, StoresNumber = 3},
    new CountryStat{Country = "Italy", MinPrice = 2.25M, StoresNumber = 4},
    new CountryStat{Country = "Slovenia", MinPrice = 0.0M, StoresNumber = 0},
    new CountryStat{Country = "Ukraine", MinPrice = 1.20M, StoresNumber = 7},
});
```

I had an idea to group `storedPriceList` by `GoodId` and then select min `Price`, but I have no idea what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `goodList` left join `storePriceList` by matching `Id` with `GoodId`
2. Group by `Country`
3. Select:

   3.1. Get min value of `Price`

   3.2. Remove `Shop` with null, distinct value and perform count
4. Order by `Country`

```cs
(
    from a in goodList
    join b in storePriceList on a.Id equals b.GoodId into ab
    from b in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group new 
    { 
        Country = a.Country, 
        Price = b == null ? 0 : b.Price,
        Shop = b == null ? null : b.Shop
    } by a.Country into g
    select new
    {
        Country = g.Key,
        MinPrice = g.Min(x => x.Price),
        StoresNumber = g.Where(x => x.Shop != null)
                        .Select(x => x.Shop)
                        .Distinct()
                        .Count()
    }
)
.OrderBy(x => x.Country)
.ToList();
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wjnSv4)

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = goodList
        .Select(x => x.Country).Distinct()
        .GroupJoin(
            goodList.Join(storePriceList, good => good.Id, price => price.GoodId,
                (good, goodsGroup) =>
                    new
                    {
                        Good = good,
                        Prices = goodsGroup
                    }), country => country, goods => goods.Good.Country,
            (country, goods) => new
            {
                Country = country,
                Goods = goods
            })
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(x =>
            new CountryStat
            {
                Country = x.Country,
                MinPrice = x.Goods.Any() ? x.Goods.Select(y => y.Prices).Min(y => y.Price) : decimal.Zero,
                StoresNumber = x.Goods.Any() ? x.Goods.Select(y => y.Prices).DistinctBy(y => y.Shop).Count() : 0
            })
        .OrderBy(x => x.Country)
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

you could `Select` countries in a list and remove repeated elements (hence a list of all countries). and from there you can easily divide the main list into list of list of goods per country (`List<(string Country, List<prices>)>`)